# How to find out if InsertLeave was the result of a change

Tags: vim

In Vim there are basically two types of commands that can make it go into insert mode:

Commands that just add something, such as: `i`, `I`, `a`, `A` (apart from using backspace).
Or, that also remove a piece of text, such as: `c[motion]`, `C`, `s`, `v[motions]s`.

I would like to hook the `InsertLeave` event, but in my code I need to know which type of change it was (an insert like `i`, or a change like `cw`). Is there any way to find that out?

Comment: I believe `InsertEnter` is just that, whether the user entered insert mode or not. I'm not aware of any way to find out exactly how though...

Comment: Well, it does seem possible. The best I've come up with so far is `au! InsertEnter * let b:lastwaschange = getpos("'.")==getpos(".")` which looks whether the position of the last change is equal to the current position, but unfortunately it does not work for `I` (nor `o` and `O`).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a different approach.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is see whether the original text matches a certain regex, and if so propagate the change throughout the buffer. It's a bit similar to the `ChangeGlobally` plugin, but I'm hoping to make it automatic.

Comment: I'm the author of _ChangeGlobally_ :-) I chose a different command (`gc`) to make the behavior explicit (and implementation easier), but your use case may be different. Where exactly would you want this automatic global replacement to occur? Do you have an example?

Comment: Cool! I'm working on a script similar to [Stakeholders](https://github.com/tomtom/stakeholders_vim/), mostly to see if I can make a lightweight version of it (and for fun). The idea is to look for changes in patterns like `for(int <+FOO+>=0; <+FOO+><len; <+FOO+>++){<+BAR+>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `i<BS><BS><BS>bar` count as insertion or change? If the latter, you could `:undo` the change on `InsertLeave`, store the lines affected by it (i.e. `'[,']`), `:redo`, then compare both sets. If there's "just more text", it's an insertion, else a change.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea! Do you have any experience with/do you think it could be done with `undotree()` (to not have to actually undo stuff)?

Comment: I don't think you can get the actual contents from `undotree()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one difference that you may be able to exploit: The change commands all modify a register (unless the black-hole register was explicitly specified by prepending `"_`), whereas insertions do not (well, except for `".`).

If you take a "snapshot" of the default register before (e.g. with a `CursorMoved,CursorHold` combo) and compare the contents on `InsertLeave`, you can find out.

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about that. The only problem is that the register might stay the same if the same text is edited (for example, if you do something like `ciwfoo<esc>uciwbar<esc>` on a word). And I don't think it's a good idea to just empty that register to try and fix that. :)